# Do I need to close FileOutputStream object?

Tags: java, apache-poi, fileoutputstream

In my code I am using a Apache POI library class - `HSSFWorkbook`.

```
try {
    testBook.write(outputStream);
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new ExportException(e);
}
```

As you can see I am passing a `FileOutputStream` object to the `write()` method.
My question is, is there any need of closing this stream object in a finally block or POI does it internally ?

I have seen that `POIFSFileSystem.writeFilesystem()` method is called from `HSSFWorkbook.write()` method and in `writeFilesystem()`
method following code is written where stream object is getting passed to `writeBlocks()` method. But I am not sure at runtime 
which instance of which class `writer` variable will refer to. So I dont know at the end what is happening to that stream object.

Please help.

```
iter = writers.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext())
{
    BlockWritable writer = ( BlockWritable ) iter.next();

    writer.writeBlocks(stream);
}
```

Comment: Wrap it in a `try-with-resources` block and don't worry about it.

Comment: Also consult the javadocs - that is what they are for

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen `outputStream` is passed as a method param . So I cant declare it in `try-with-resources` staement

Comment: You're declaring it somewhere, no?

Comment: I have declared that OS variable and passing it to a method. I have mentioned body of that method

Comment: In general closing an output stream twice shouldn't be a problem but leaving it open could be a serious problem. ;)

Answer (score 1):

[The Javadoc for the method](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook.html#write-java.io.OutputStream-) does not mention closing the stream, so you are responsible for closing it if necessary. Note that in fact [the implementation *does not* close the stream](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/poi/3.7/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook.java#HSSFWorkbook.write%28java.io.OutputStream%29); in theory, this could facilitate something like implementing a serialized form.